# fwrite() and fread() struct array writes nothing in file in C

Tags: c

Im having a hard time inputting the data to the file, whenever I input data to struct array then saves it to text file, fwrite() prints nothing to the file.

```
int last;
struct Person{
    int pid;
    char lname[MAXchar], fname[MAXchar], mname[MAXchar];
    int age;
    char subject[MAXchar];
    float grade;
};
struct Person Num[MAX];
struct Person *No;
```

and this is how I save it to the text file.

```
void saveDATA(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("database.txt","ab");

    fwrite(No, sizeof(struct Person), 1, fp);

    if(fwrite != 0)
        printf("Success!\n");
    else
        printf("error!\n");

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Although the program says it returns, fwrite doesnt print any data at the text file

and this is how I load the data to return it to the struct array but its not working

```
void loadDATA(){
    FILE *fp;
    char line[500];
    fp=fopen("database.dbf","rb+");
    if(fp == NULL){
        fp = fopen("database.dbf", "wb");
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        last++;
        fscanf(line,"%d %s %s %s %d %s %2.f", &array[last].pid, array[last].lname, array[last].fname,array[last].mname, &array[last].age, array[last].subject, &array[last].grade);
        insert(array.tempID, array.L, array.F, array.M, array.TempAge, array.Sub, array.Tempgrade);

    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `if(fwrite != 0)` in this line fwrite is always not 0. It's the pointer to the fwrite function into the program. To have the result, you may use `i=fwrite(No, [...])` then if (i)

Comment: The call to fwrite you use will write only an element of the struct. If you want to write all element of the struct you have to use `fwrite(No, sizeof(struct Person), MAX, fp);`

Comment: Where's your `main` function?

Comment: Also, you cannot read binary data using the `fgets` function. You have to use the `fread` function.

Comment: @SirJoBlack I tried this one but still no luck, I still get nothing at the text file.

Comment: What did you try? I said you a lot of things! If you read the file with fgets you have not correct results.

Comment: @SirJoBlack I tried the fwrite you've said, I checked the file but there's nothing in there.

Comment: @SirJoBlack thank you for giving your time to help me, I tried different method of saving the data to file. And it worked!

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(No, sizeof(struct Person), 1, fp);

    if(fwrite != 0)`  This is nonsense.  Suggest: `if( fwrite(No, sizeof(struct Person), 1, fp) !=1 ) { // handle error }`

Comment: regarding: `fp = fopen("database.dbf", "wb");`  Using the "w" mode always results in the file being truncated to zero length

Comment: regarding: `fp=fopen("database.dbf","rb+");`  The data in the file is not 'binary' so should not use the `b` mode and your not going to be writing to the file, so the `+` should not be used.   Note When calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        last++;`  The variable `last` has not been initialized, (probably should be initialized to 0).  So `last` contains what ever trash was on the stack at its' location.  The result (most likely) will be a very large number or a negative number.  Either condition results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: in general, since there is no line separator being written to the file, the call to `fgets()` will actually read near 500 bytes (unless EOF encountered) or some data in the strings in the structs, in the bytes that have not been initialized, happens to contain a EOF sequence or a newline sequence.  I.E. always initialize the struct to ALL '\0', perhaps via `memset()`, before assigning data to the fields

Comment: note: when calling `fwrite()`, the returned value, if other than the same as the third parameter, indicates some kind of failure occurred.   Check returned values from C library functions to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `        printf("Success!\n");
    else
        printf("error!\n");`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  And when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  A simple way to do this is by calling: `perror( "your error message" );`